# Условие для EventTrigger - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `Image` со стилем, который размещен на `MyControl : UserControl`, в `MyControl` есть свойство `IsSelected`.

```
<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0.4" To="1" Duration="0:0:.25"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.4" Duration="0:0:.25"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Как задать условие типа: Если `MyControl.IsSelected` то выполнять тригеры, если нет то не выполнять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `MultiDataTrigger` на `IsMouseOver` и `IsSelected`:

```xaml
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=self:MyControl}}" Value="True"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0.4" To="1" Duration="0:0:.25"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.4" Duration="0:0:.25"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Или вы можете дать имя корневому элементу в `UserControl`'е, и сослаться на него прямо:

```
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=Root}" Value="True"/>
```

Не забудьте установить начальное значение `Opacity` в 0.4!

---

Обновление: Если вы хотите, чтобы триггеры начинали срабатывать только на MouseIn/Out, а не в то время, когда контрол получает `IsSelected`, можно сделать так:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SO16.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:self="clr-namespace:SO16"
             Height="30"
             x:Name="Root">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="SelectedImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:.25"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="0.4" Duration="0:0:.25"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Grid>
                <Image Name="InnerImage" Source="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" Height="30" Opacity="0.4"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="self:MyControl.IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="InnerImage" Value="{StaticResource SelectedImageStyle}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Я убрал контент в `Template`, отделил стиль в ресурсы, и в `DoubleAnimation` убрал `From`.

Comment: Да, я точно так же и реализовал, прям один в один как у Вас. Но была такая проблема, когда свойство `IsSelected` менялось на `True` и в этот момент мышка была на контроле(когда кликнул и Имедж как бы стал `IsSelected`) то анимация сработала и затемнила картинку. Пока что решил вот так, анимация входа у меня `FillBehavior="HoldEnd"` а выхода `FillBehavior="Stop"`, немного мигает конечно, но в результате работает как нужно, может быть если еще решение этой проблемы? И еще, `{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=Root` вот так вот не хочет во обще работать почему то...

Comment: @SkyDancer: А вы не забыли корневому элементу в `UserControl` дать имя `Root`?

Comment: @SkyDancer: обновил ответ.